# LaTex seems to read a file (natbib) when I have cancelled

Tags: bibliographies

[image]I am writing my bibliography using a package created in Spain, which name is flexbib. However, before I installed it I tried with natbib, which I didn't use at the end. I wrote the first chapter of my thesis without problems. However, I have recently started my second chapter and I get an error message. Apparently or at least according to the error message, LaTex is ignoring flexbib and using natbib, which doesn't generate the entry. I have attached 2 screenshot. How can I tell LaTex to use flexbib instead of natbib. I have already cancelled natbib using the symbol %. Would it be a solution to uninstall the package from miktek?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: please don't post code or error messages as images it is impossible to debug. If you posted a small example and the log file as text someone could easily tell where natbib is included

Comment: uninstalling the package would definitely not help.

Comment: Many thanks@DavidCarlisle. The error message says citation undefined, do you know what could it be due to?

Comment: if you go `\cite{wibble}` and don't have an entry for `wibble` in your generated bibliography then you get that warning. Either `wibble` is not in your bib file, or you have not run bibtex to generate the bibliography

Comment: Many, many thanks @DavidCarlisle. It was due to a very silly mistake, as I had forgotten to run bibtex. I am sorry for my clumsiness

Answer (score 3):

assuming that the file you are using is

https://github.com/JornadasR/VJornadas/blob/master/flexbib.sty

It somewhat confusingly uses `\PackageWarning{natbib}%` for all its warnings, so making them seem as if they come from natbib.

this is presumably because the file is a modified version of  natbib and the author didn't change the warning strings. You should report that and ask for it to be changed as it is confusing if not exactly wrong.